# ListView Adapter executing onclick methods on multiple rows simultaneously for a single click event

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

In my app I have a `listview` in a tab `fragment`. Each row of `listview` is a `cardview` , which has multiple views in it.(`Buttons`, `textviews` etc.) I have created a custom `adapter` class for this `listview`.

This `adapter` class takes the data from local DB and inserts it in different `views` in `cardview`, creating a list of cards. I have a like button in `cardview`.

Now, when user presses the like button, I'm changing the background of button with a `onClickListener` on button in adapter class.

The problem is, if I press like button on one card, it will change the background of like button on that card as well as like button on forth card down in the list. I think this has to do something with `ViewHolder` pattern I'm using, but not sure how to fix it.

Here is the Custom Adapter class

```
package com.example.nxtstepz.nxtstepzone.Adpters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.nxtstepz.nxtstepzone.Communicater.Communicater;
import com.example.nxtstepz.nxtstepzone.PostDetailActivity;
import com.example.nxtstepz.nxtstepzone.PostInfo;
import com.example.nxtstepz.nxtstepzone.R;
import java.util.List;
import de.greenrobot.dao.query.QueryBuilder;
import nxtstepz.DaoMaster;
import nxtstepz.DaoSession;
import nxtstepz.Post;
import nxtstepz.PostDao;
import nxtstepz.SavedPost;
import nxtstepz.SavedPostDao;

/**
 * Created by Prathya on 6/8/2015.
 */
public class HomeScreenNewsFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostInfo>{
List<PostInfo> data;
Context context;
int layoutid;
public HomeScreenNewsFeedAdapter(Context context, int layoutid,     List<PostInfo> data) {
    super(context, layoutid);
    this.context=context;
    this.data=data;
    this.layoutid=layoutid;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class PostHolder{
    TextView postusername,autherinstitute,postheading,postdescription,likecount,comments,date,category;
    View save,like;
    LinearLayout postdetail;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context,"nxtstepz",null);
    SQLiteDatabase db =helper.getWritableDatabase();
    DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    DaoSession session = daoMaster.newSession();
    final PostDao postDao = session.getPostDao();
   final PostHolder holder;
    View v= convertView;
    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v= li.inflate(layoutid,parent,false);
        holder = new PostHolder();
        holder.postusername = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.postusername);
        holder.autherinstitute= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.autherinstitute);
        holder.postheading = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        holder.postdescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        holder.likecount = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.like_count);
        holder.comments = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
        holder.date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_datetime);
        holder.category = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_category);
        holder.save=v.findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        holder.like= v.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
        holder.postdetail=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll3);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder= (PostHolder)v.getTag();
    }
  final PostInfo post;
     post = data.get(position);
    Log.d("post id", String.valueOf(post.posttypeid));
    holder.postusername.setText(post.postusername);
    holder.autherinstitute.setText(post.autherinstitutename);
    holder.postheading.setText(post.postheading);
    holder.postdescription.setText(post.postdescription);
    holder.likecount.setText(""+post.likecount);
    holder.comments.setText("" + post.comments);
    holder.category.setText(post.categoryname);
    holder.date.setText(post.date);

    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //this method has the problem
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (post.postlikeflag == 0) {
                holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.liked);
                post.postlikeflag =1;
            } else {
                holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like);
                post.postlikeflag = 0;
            }


        }
    });
    holder.postdetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent eventDetail = new Intent(context, PostDetailActivity.class);
            eventDetail.putExtra("EventDetail", post);
            context.startActivity(eventDetail);

        }
    });


return  v;
 }
}
```

Here is the single_card_view.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#BDBDBD">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/homecardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/postusername"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Jessica Alba"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:id="@+id/autherinstitute"
                    android:text="Mahatma audkjfsdk dkbldvb"
                    android:singleLine="true"

                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="38 min"
                    android:id="@+id/post_datetime"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#9C27B0"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00b5ad"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Sri-Ram breakup party"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Monica is an Italian actress and model who recently broke up with Sriram started her modelling career at the age of 13 by posing for a local photo enthusiast. Android:The Best OS.Android powers hundreds of millions of mobile devices in more than 190 countries around the world.Android's openness has made it a favorite for consumers"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#000000"></View>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/like_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/like"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

            </View>

            <View
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/comment"
                android:id="@+id/comment_button"></View>

            <View
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
                android:id="@+id/save_button"
                android:background="@drawable/save"></View>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/like_count"
                android:background="#FFECB3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/like_button"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/like_button"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/like_button"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/comment_count"
                android:background="#FFECB3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/comment_button"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment_button"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/comment_button" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: for that you need to update the specific position like from List<PostInfo> data list

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using HashMap as SAM suggested.
Here is what I did.

in Adapter class

```
HashMap<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
```

in `getView()`method of `adapter`

```
    if(post.postlikeflag==0){
      map.put(post.postid, "like");
      }
     else{
           map.put(post.postid,"liked");
      }

   if(map.get(post.postid).equals("like")) {
            holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like);
        }
      else {
          holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.liked);
        }
```

And in `onclickListener` of like button

```
  if (post.postlikeflag == 0 && map.get(post.postid).equals("like")) {
                holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.liked);
                map.put(post.postid, "liked");
                post.postlikeflag = 1;
  } else {
                holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like);
                post.postlikeflag = 0;
                map.put(post.postid,"like");
      }
```

I know there can be some redundancy in the code. Point it out if you find.

Answer (score 1):

i have modifiedyour code paste it and check wether it is working or not

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context,"nxtstepz",null);
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = new  HashMap<Integer, String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db =helper.getWritableDatabase();
        DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        DaoSession session = daoMaster.newSession();
        final PostDao postDao = session.getPostDao();
       final PostHolder holder;
        View v= convertView;
        if(v==null){
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            v= li.inflate(layoutid,parent,false);
            holder = new PostHolder();
            holder.postusername = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.postusername);
            holder.autherinstitute= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.autherinstitute);
            holder.postheading = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            holder.postdescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
            holder.likecount = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.like_count);
            holder.comments = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
            holder.date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_datetime);
            holder.category = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_category);
            holder.save=v.findViewById(R.id.save_button);
            holder.like= v.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
            holder.postdetail=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll3);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder= (PostHolder)v.getTag();
        }
      final PostInfo post;
         post = data.get(position);
        Log.d("post id", String.valueOf(post.posttypeid));
        holder.postusername.setText(post.postusername);
        holder.autherinstitute.setText(post.autherinstitutename);
        holder.postheading.setText(post.postheading);
        holder.postdescription.setText(post.postdescription);
        holder.likecount.setText(""+post.likecount);
        holder.comments.setText("" + post.comments);
        holder.category.setText(post.categoryname);
        holder.date.setText(post.date);
        map.put(position,"like");
        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //this method has the problem
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (post.postlikeflag == 0 && map.get(position).equals("like")) {
                    holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.liked);
                    map.put(position,"liked");
                    post.postlikeflag =1;
                } else {
                    holder.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like);
                    post.postlikeflag = 0;
                }


            }
        });
        holder.postdetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent eventDetail = new Intent(context, PostDetailActivity.class);
                eventDetail.putExtra("EventDetail", post);
                context.startActivity(eventDetail);

            }
        });
```

Comment: It's having couple of errors. First is, it says map is accessed from inner class and needs to be declared final. And second one is in map.put(position, "like") it says wrong 1st argument type, found int requires String.

Comment: change the first parameter from string to int like this `HashMap<Integer, String> map;` declare the `hashmap` global in your `adapter class` then it will work

Comment: yes i put your code and checked it. looks like issue is still there.

Comment: I got it ! after a long time !  I used hashmap as you suggested and finally got it working. !

Answer (score 0):

In your button and other view where onClick listener is there add these two line in  xml

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

declare final variable index as below and initialize it with position at very 
start of getView method as below

```
final int index = position;
```

Also on click instead of this

```
 post.postlikeflag =1;
```

try this

```
data.get(index).postlikeflag = 1;
```

also you will have to call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Ya, It's giving an error message, "variable 'position' is accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80773/discussion-between-apk-and-prathmesh-deshmukh).

Comment: use hashmap to maintain the state of view because list view reuses the view.

Comment: I never came across it before. Could you please give some tutorial link, or a simple example. That would be really helpful.